# Dynamic concatenated string creation in Python

Tags: python, string, loops

[the problem I'm working on](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=29&page=show_problem&problem=1083)

So I'm creating a 'Aussie' ballot app and I'm looking for a creative solution to an input prompt.

Basically the user inputs how many people, and then submits up to 1000 votes or w/e.

Assuming 3 candidates the input prompt would look something like:

```
ballot = raw_input('1 for %s: 2 for %s: 3 for %s: ') % (cand_list[0], cand_list[1], cand_list[2])
```

But what I'd really like to come up with is a dynamic prompt (assume the user enters 5, 10, w/e number of candidates)

I've looked into separating the ballot assignment and printing, or creating a ballot string entirely separate and passing it(assuming I can make some kind of stringbuilder function), but I'm curious to see other approaches. Still tinkering with it to see if I'll need to escape the % formatting.

[Python Stringbuilder(sort of)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space) and 
[More string concat](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this using string formatting, `str.join` and `enumerate`:

```
>>> candidates = ['foo', 'bar', 'spam']
>>> print ' : '.join('{} for {}'.format(i, c) for i, c in enumerate(candidates, 1))
1 for foo : 2 for bar : 3 for spam

>>> candidates = ['foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'python', 'guido']
>>> print ' : '.join('{} for {}'.format(i, c) for i, c in enumerate(candidates, 1))
1 for foo : 2 for bar : 3 for spam : 4 for python : 5 for guido
```

Comment: why zip range instead of `enumerate(canidates,1)`?

Comment: works great! i'll tinker with getting the newline after the enumeration

Answer (score 0):

Construct your format string separately in stages:

```
inner_format_string = "{num} for %s: "
full_format_string = " ".join(inner_format_string.format(num=i) for i in xrange(1, len(cand_list) + 1))

ballot = raw_input(full_format_string % tuple(cand_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
canidates = ["Frank","Bill","Joe","Suzy"]
raw_input(", ".join("Enter %d For %s"%(num,canidate) for num,canidate in enumerate(canidates,1)))
```

perhaps

Comment: almost perfect, just have to prevent a new line after each candidate